# Behavior dependent on sql server edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to prepare sql script which will be triggered periodically and will behave differently on MS SQL Server Enterprise edition than others. 
I know that I can check edition by:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition')
```

so i thought that it can work like this:

```
IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as edition WHERE edition LIKE '%Enterprise')
BEGIN
    print 'script for enterprise edition'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print 'script for other verisons'
END
```

but I can't refer to field aliases in the WHERE clause and get error "Invalid column name 'edition'.", so I tried to use CTE:

```
WITH Test AS (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as edition)
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE edition LIKE '%Enterprise'
```

but it didn't work either ("Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of like function.")

Do you have any suggestion how to achieve behavior dependent on edition?

Comment: Er, why?  Are you attempting to avoid some feature that isn't present?  If this is an attempt to limit your deployed app in some fashion (for payment tiers, essentially), this can be gotten around...

Comment: No, I just want to rebuild indexes, but only on Enterprise edition I can rebuild in without maintenance downtime, so on Standard edition (I'm only supporting thoose two editions) I just want to reorganize indexes in all cases (no matter of fragmentation level). On Enterprise I will reorganize indexes when frag level is between 10 and 30% and rebuild when above.

Comment: ...You might want to run this plan by the people on [dba.se]; re-orging/rebuilding indices isn't something I'd likely fully automate (however, I haven't done that much on the actual admin end).

Comment: I know that it not best practice to fully automate this, because triggering period should depend on frequency of R/W operations on table and percentage value of fragmentation on which index should be rebuilt depends on size of table. However for my purposes that should be enough :) - I will use this only for some tables that I have for caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the check:

```
if (cast(serverproperty('edition') as varchar) like '%enterprise%')
    print 'script for enterprise edition'
else
    print 'script for other verisons'
```

Answer (score 0):

%Store Results of SERVERPROPERTY to a variable:

```
DECLARE @Edition SYSNAME
SELECT @Edition = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS SYSNAME)

IF (@Edition LIKE '%Enterprise%')
BEGIN
    print 'script for enterprise edition'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print 'script for other verisons'
END
```

EDIT: Updated as per comment by @marc_s

Comment: Since the `SERVERPROPERTY` probably returns `Enterprise Edition (64-bit)`, you'll need to use `IF (@Edition LIKE '%Enterprise%')` (with a trailing `%`) to get your desired results